# Selenium webdriver not selecting username input element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[www.academia.srmuniv.ac.in](http://academia.srmuniv.ac.in) is the website. I am scripting using Python 2.7 and am performing it on Chrome. I wish to select the'email address' input element from the page. I have tried all the selectors but it just doesnt seem to work. Says it is unable to locate the element.

Its not a problem with my configuration because I am able to select elements on other websites. But on this website, I was unable to select the email address input, the password input and the sign in button.

Is it a security thing they have enabled to prevent such acts? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to several `iframe` elements before interacting with elements inside form:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@urltype="zc_cpLoginUrl"]'))
driver.switch_to.frame('zohoiam')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked but can you please explain how this works?

Comment: [`iframe`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) is a separate HTML document with its own DOM. Elements inside this DOM is unaccessible until you [switch to `iframe`](https://computerrecipes.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/selenium-webdriver-interact-with-an-element-inside-an-iframe/). You can check ancestors of required email input field and you'll find something like `<iframe name="zohoiam">`. You can use `@name` to identify `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

The `Email Address` field is located within an **`iframe`** with **`name`** attribute as **`zohoiam`** which is again within an **`iframe`** with **`urltype`** attribute set to **`zc_cpLoginUrl`**. So we have to switch within 2 **`iframes`** to interact with the **`Email Address`** field as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/login.jsp')
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@urltype='zc_cpLoginUrl']")
driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "zohoiam"))
    )
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='Email']").send_keys("debanjan")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./drivers/geckodriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("https://academia.srmuniv.ac.in/");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@iscustomerportal='true']"));
      driver.switchTo().frame(ele);
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@frameborder='0']"));
      driver.switchTo().frame(ele1);
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("StackOverflow@mail.in");
      String s= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']")).getText();
      System.out.println(s);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("hello");
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn']")).click();
```

Comment: Nothing security check , Just you have apply the concept of frames in selenium,then you are good to go.